# Synchronize random edge to clock edge

Tags: clock, random, edge

I have a steady clock signal and another signal with random binary pulses. Is there a simple circuit that can detect the rising edge of the random pulses and generate a pulse that is synchronized to the clock's rising edge? For example:

```
Clock:  000111000111000111000111000111000
Signal: 000011000000011110000001110000000
Output: 000000000111000111000000000111000
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is it just me, or it is totally unclear what the relation between the signals is?

Comment: Do you want the "signal" high to enable the next clock to propagate to the output?`

Comment: Apparently, his output changes state only when Clock transitions from 0 to 1.

Comment: The signal is asynchronous with respect to the clock. The desired output is synchronized to the rising edge of the clock. That is if there is a rising edge between two clock rising edges, the output has a rising edge corresponding to the second clock rising edge.

Comment: @gbarry Not really... it is dropping to `0` without this transition.

Comment: OK, let's try to go the other way around. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to sample an A/D sample at the clock edge when it is triggered by the signal.

Comment: So you want your signal to act as "enable" signal for synchronous sampling of some other signal. This is the correct problem statement. D-latch is doing this (sample-and-hold).

Comment: Yes. The signal tells when to sample and the clock tells when the other signal can be sampled.

Comment: Obviously it is not what you have asked initially. One signal (the sampled one) is missing.

Comment: This is so confusing.... My brain hurts reading your question.  Your signal output does not make sense either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's simple - except that it's not. The classic circuit is something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5ZH4A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will produce a single-period pulse for every rising edge, with two important caveats:

1 - The pulses must be greater in width than the clock period (or the first FF may miss it), and the same goes for the inter-pulse period.

2 - (and this is where it gets tricky). Every once in a while, an edge will occur just as a clock edge occurs, and for any FF this will produce what is known as a metastable condition, with the output of the first FF in an unknown state for an unknown period of time. This is countered by adding flip-flops to the left-hand part of the circuit, with the number of FFs determined by things like the IC technology and the maximum allowable error rate. You can start with [the Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metastability_in_electronics).

EDIT - If the input pulses are narrower than the sample clock, then you can simply apply a one-shot with an output pulse slightly wider than the sample period, and use this as the data input to the circuit shown. An example of such an IC is the 74HC4538.

And there is no way around metastabilty issues.

Comment: What if the signal pulse width is only wider than the clock pulse but narrower than the clock period?

Comment: If the signal edge occurs at the same time as the clock edge, it is okay if it is not detected within the same clock pulse but in the next clock pulse.

Comment: Given the discussion in the comment it doesn't seem to be the thing the OP is after...

Comment: @Bin - See edit.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - Thank you for your answer, it gives me a solid baseline to work with. Appreciate your help very much.